# Why does this work? Executing method from IL without instance

Tags: c#, .net, il

I was looking through [*What's the strangest corner case you've seen in C# or .NET?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3934725), and this code made me think a little:

```
public class Program
{
    delegate void HelloDelegate(Strange bar);

    [STAThread()]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Strange bar = null;
        var hello = new DynamicMethod("ThisIsNull",
            typeof(void), new[] { typeof(Strange) },
         typeof(Strange).Module);
        ILGenerator il = hello.GetILGenerator(256);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        var foo = typeof(Strange).GetMethod("Foo");
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, foo);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        var print = (HelloDelegate)hello.CreateDelegate(typeof(HelloDelegate));
        print(bar);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    internal sealed class Strange
    {
       public void Foo()
       {
           Console.WriteLine(this == null);
       }
    }
}
```

I do understand what the code does, but I do not understand why it works. Isn't that like doing `null.Foo()`? It works as if `Foo()` is static, and this is being called instead: `Strange.Foo();`.

Would you please tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`this` is implemented as a normal parameter; your code simply passes `null` as this parameter.

The only reason that this would normally throw a `NullReferenceException` is that methods are usually called using the `CallVirt` instruction, which does a vtable lookup on the `this` parameter and throws if it's null.

If you use `call`, the method will execute perfectly fine even if `this` is null, although the method itself will likely end up throwing later.

Comment: That is very very interesting! Thank you very much for your answer :)
I was not aware of the difference between `OpCodes.Callvirt` and `OpCodes.Call`. A small search guided me to this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2008/07/02/why-does-c-always-use-callvirt.aspx
And indeed, in the code above, changing `il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, foo);` to `il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, foo);` throws an exception.
Thank you once again!

Comment: +1. [Why does C# compiler produce method call to call BaseClass method in IL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219188/why-does-c-sharp-compiler-produce-method-call-to-call-baseclass-method-in-il?rq=1) discusses some reasons of using `callvirt` in a bit more details if one is interested.

Comment: Incidentally, this is why the compiler's use of `call` to implement `base.Foo();` calls is technically a spec violation: the C# spec requires `base.Foo();` to throw a `NullReferenceException` if `this == null`. (Of course, if anyone actually cares to fix that, the fix will probably be to change the spec.)

Comment: @hvd: Is there any spec-legal way for `this` to be `null` in the first place?

Comment: @SLaks Sure, call it from another method implemented in a language other than C#. The C# spec doesn't require methods not written in C# to adhere to C#'s rules and a large point of .NET is to enable interoperability between different languages. This question is a spec-legal way to get `this == null`.